# TYPO3 OG property meta tags issue

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

Im running TYPO3 v. 6.1 with FLUID and EXTBASE, i have the following extensions installed.

News system     news    2.2.1

RealURL: speaking paths for TYPO3   realurl     1.12.7

by some risen i got some meta tags, that i haven't added.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Perfect test site" />
```

I haven't added the text "Perfect test site" anywhere, so my question is.. where can i find something about these two meta tags and changes the value of em ?

Comment: Did you check the settings for plugin.tx_news.opengraph.site_name in the constant editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TypoScript setup, just change the values for the key "opengraph":

```
# Opengraph implementation
    opengraph {
        site_name = Your Site Name
        type = article
        admins =
        email =
        phone_number =
        fax_number =
        latitude =
        longitude =
        street-address =
        locality =
        region =
        postal-code =
        country-name =
    }
```

Those default values comes from the static template of EXT:news

Answer (score 0):

This only works from tx_news 2.3.0